# Perl error with grep and split handling in variables

Tags: string, perl

I am trying to assign output of grep into variable but I get numeric as output.

Case I:

output of

```
print ( grep !/create/i&&!/or/i &&!/replace/i&&!/package/i&&!/body/i&&!/as/i ,  split ( / / , $str1[0] ) );
```

Case II:

is string but output of

```
my $pname = grep !/create/i&&!/or/i &&!/replace/i&&!/package/i&&!/body/i&&!/as/i ,  split ( / / , $str1[0] ) ;
print $pname , "\n";
```

is number

What is difference and how do I get string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Like many Perl functions (and operators), `grep` does slightly different things in list context and scalar context. Its different return behaviours are explained in [its documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting
>   $_ to each element) and returns the list value consisting of those
>   elements for which the expression evaluated to true. In scalar
>   context, returns the number of times the expression was true.

In your first example, `print` imposes list context on the expression, so you get a list of values back. In your second example, you assign the results to a scalar, so `grep` gets called in scalar context and returns the number of matches found.

The solution is to ensure that `grep` is called in list context. Two easy ways to do this are to do a list assignment:

```
my ($pname) = grep ...;
```

Or by assigning the results to an array;

```
my @pnames = grep ...;
```

You'll find Perl programming a lot easier if you get used to consulting [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org).

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `grep`, you are dealing with lists. `grep` takes input as a list, and produces a list as output.

Whenever an array is evaluated in scalar context (such as assigning to a scalar variable), it returns its length. Whenever it is evaluated in list context, it returns the array itself. In this case grep works in the same way as an array, returning the length of the list returned from grep when evaluated in scalar context.

```
my $pname = grep { 
               !/create/i&&!/or/i &&!/replace/i&&!/package/i&&!/body/i&&!/as/i  
            } split / /, $str1[0]);
print $pname , "\n";
```

will return the size of the list returned from grep because `$pname` is a scalar variable.

```
my ($pname) = grep { 
               !/create/i&&!/or/i &&!/replace/i&&!/package/i&&!/body/i&&!/as/i  
            } split / /, $str1[0]);
print $pname , "\n";
```

Will return the *first* element of the list, because the assignment is performed in list context (notice the parens around `$pname`).

Here is a brief overview of context: http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl

Comment: "Whenever a List is evaluated in scalar context (such as assigning to a scalar variable), it returns its length" - I can see why you might think this is true (and in this case that's certainly how `grep` acts) but this isn't true in the general case. Lists do **not** return their length in scalar context - that is arrays. Arrays and lists are **not** the same thing. I wrote [this blog post](http://perlhacks.com/2013/12/misunderstanding-context/) to try and clarify this concept.

Comment: @DaveCross Thanks, I will correct it. I actually read your article a few weeks ago and I *still* get it wrong. doh!